# Converting HashMap Error Message content to JSON

Tags: java, html, json, angularjs

So I'm struggling to find a solution to this issue, I've currently got a function on the front end which relies on an error message in the back end. This error section is summarised to this:

```
HashMap<Long, Integer> serviceListResponse = new HashMap<>();
...
if (!serviceListResponse.isEmpty()) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.valueOf(serviceListResponse));
}
```

So I thought this should be straight forward to parse:

```
$log.info(JSON.stringify(errorResponse.data.message))
log message = "{16=2140002475, 17=2140002724, 18=2140002116, 8=2140034827}"
$scope.listOfIds = JSON.parse(errorResponse.data.message);
```

However it doesn't seem to be passing the JSON.parse and therefore ending at that particular line. I've used JSON.parse before for ArrayLists and had no issues, so what am I doing wrong for this? Thanks.

Comment: Your problem is with `String.valueOf(serviceListResponse)` this returns, `{16=2140002475}` string, for JSON `=` operator is not recognizable it need `:` as in `key:value` to parse the string. You can use `JacksonObjectMapper.writeValueAsString()`. https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#writeValueAsString(java.lang.Object)

Comment: @Zedex7 is there anyway I can do that on the front end?

Comment: Absolutely, but it is not recommended. Here is the JS Snippet how you can do that `"{16=123445}".replace('=',':')` -> `"{16:123445}"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 problems with your code. First you are not using `ObjectMapper` which basically take care of converting response to JSON in Java. Second since a raw string is coming in response it has characters that won't let you parse the response.

Like `"{16=2140002475,..}"`, response is already a string so `JSON.stringify` won't work, it'll just prefix and suffix double quotes `""{16=2140002475, ..}""`. Second even if you somehow manage to remove quotes, Your key is Number & delimiter is `=` both are not identified by `JSON.parse`, it need Key as String & delimiter as `:`.

Since you do not want to change code in Java (still highly recommended), I gave a try to parse your response in JS. What you need is a custom parser which will convert your response string to JS dictionary and then you can directly use it without `JSON.parse`.

```js
function customParse(message) {
  var msgArray = message.replace(/[{}]/g, '').split(',');
  var dict = {};
  for (var data of msgArray) {
    var obj = data.split('=');
    dict[obj[0].trim()] = obj[1];
  }
  return dict;
}

var message = "{16=2140002475, 17=2140002724, 18=2140002116, 8=2140034827}";
console.log(customParse(message));
```

*Note: This will not work if you introduce any nested HashMap in your original Java map.*

Comment: Hey, would there be any possibly this could be updated to Multimap response or would I need to create a new question instead? So this output {1=[2140001792, 2140001793]} to similar {1=2140001792, 1=2140001793}

Comment: `HashMap<Long, Integer> serviceListResponse = new HashMap<>()` this won't allow such response in first place.

Comment: I understand, but if that HashMap was changed to MultiMap and that {1=[2140001792, 2140001793]} would be the response. Could we change the format to  {1=2140001792, 1=2140001793} and keep your existing code?

Comment: No, It won't work. May be you'll need to rewrite the entire code.